# How to implement complex-sticky section headers that replace the previous one on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way in pure css to create sticky components which conforms to following behaviour:

Suppose there are 2 sections in the HTML,

Initially, Ist section's header is on the top, 
when a user scrolls the page upwards,

it should remain sticky on top, while other 2 sections' headers should move upwards.

and when the section 2's header just touches the header 1's header, the header 1 should also start scolling upwards,

now the section 2 gets in place of section 2. and vice versa.

Comment: listening onscroll through javascript might help.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this site: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

You can write css code similary to this:

```
.header {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Live example on Codepen: https://codepen.io/dav1d-pt/pen/rNxWgOV

Keep in mind that this feature has **bad support** in many browsers. Here you can check it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Answer (score 0):

What you described is a how sticky elements work in general.

An element only stays `sticky` within its parent component, so when you define an element as sticky inside a div, that particular element behaves as its `position:fixed`. Now if another component (2nd section) now scroll into view and touches the bottom of section 1, section 2 will push the above element away upwards from the viewport.

**Codepen example & Basics:**

https://codepen.io/elad2412/embed/QYLEdK?

https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46